# ReactJS inline-style absolute top: "100vh" not working correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, absolute

I have a basic component inside of my App.js called Overlay. It's just a div and I am trying to position it using absolute positioning but when I try to set the top style from inline-styles, the component does not leave the view; however, when I set top using a separate stylesheet, it works fine. I've included side-by-side pictures of inline vs. stylesheet and would like to know how to make the inline be the same as the stylesheet. Thanks in advance.

No-Top:
[No Top Styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rJCA.png)

Inline-Top: [Inline Top Styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjNpg.png)

Stylesheet-Top: [Stylesheet Top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn3HF.png)

Code:

Overlay.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Overlay.css";

class Overlay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="Overlay" style={{ top: "calc(100vh - 60px)" }}
      ></div>
    );
  }
}

export default Overlay;
```

Overlay.css

```
.Overlay {
  height: calc(485px - 16px);
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: calc(100vh - 60px); */
}
```

Edit: The issue seems to be that react's hot-reload does not update the inline styles correctly sometimes and needs to be reloaded manually in order to get applied. Seems to be an issue on React's end.

Comment: I just tested your code and it works the same for both ways. Have a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-morse-2imy0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This code should work

Comment: That's strange... When I load it on my side it sometimes works properly other times it loads like in the picture shown. Is there something about the way react does hot-refresh that would be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, just to show you, in code, I have added backgroundColor.

```
<div className="Overlay" style={{ top: "calc(100vh - 200px)" , backgroundColor: "yellow"}}></div
```